# Makefile for C program using libpcap (dependency problems)

Tags: c, makefile, openwrt

I'm building a Makefile for a libpcap-based program. This Makefile will be used to compile the program in the OpenWrt SDK and then transfer the executable to my router. This is the Makefile:

```
path = /home/foo/Desktop/sdk/openwrt-sdk-18.06.4-x86-64_gcc- 7.3.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/staging_dir/target-x86_64_musl/usr/lib

pcap_retrans: pcap_retrans.o
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o pcap_retrans pcap_retrans.o -L$(path) -lpcap -L -libc

pcap_retrans.o: pcap_retrans.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c pcap_retrans.c cbuffer.c
```

However, the following errors appear when I "make":

```
cc  -c pcap_retrans.c cbuffer.c
cc  -o pcap_retrans pcap_retrans.o -L/home/inesmll/Desktop/sdk/openwrt-sdk-18.06.4-x86-64_gcc-7.3.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/staging_dir/target-x86_64_musl/usr/lib -lpcap -L -libc
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by 
/home/inesmll/Desktop/sdk/openwrt-sdk-18.06.4-x86-64_gcc-7.3.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/staging_dir/target-x86_64_musl/usr/lib/libpcap.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
pcap_retrans.o: In function `got_packet':
pcap_retrans.c:(.text+0x30a): undefined reference to `cbuffer_put'
pcap_retrans.c:(.text+0x334): undefined reference to `cbuffer_getretrans'
pcap_retrans.c:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `cbuffer_getnumretrans'
pcap_retrans.o: In function `main':
pcap_retrans.c:(.text+0x818): undefined reference to `cbuffer_init'
pcap_retrans.c:(.text+0x87c): undefined reference to `cbuffer_free'
/usr/bin/ld: pcap_retrans: hidden symbol `atexit' in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(atexit.oS) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'pcap_retrans' failed
make: *** [pcap_retrans] Error 1
```

I believe it has to do with the way I'm linking the cbuffer.c in the Makefile (this file is in the same folder as pcap_retrans.c), however I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: `-L -libc` --> `-libc`?  The `-L` option requires an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c pcap_retrans.c cbuffer.c` looks suspect.

You may like to compile `pcap_retrans.c` and `cbuffer.c` into separate object files. And make `pcap_retrans` depend on `pcap_retrans.o` and `cbuffer.o`. E.g.

```
pcap_retrans: pcap_retrans.o cbuffer.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -L$(path) -lpcap

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

---

Just realized that `-libc` actually links a library called `libibc.so` or `libibc.a`, not the standard C library. If that library is in directory `<dir>`, you can link it in a couple of ways:

1. Pass the full path to the library in the linker command, e.g. `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -L$(path) -lpcap <dir>/libibc.so`.
2. Specify the linker paths in the linker command, e.g. `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -L$(path) -lpcap -L<dir> -Wl,-rpath=<dir> -libc`. You can specify multiple `-Wl,-rpath=` and this is where `ld.so` (the runtime dynamic linker) will search for `libibc.so` at run-time.

Comment: I think your new structure solved one part of the problem, but if I don't add libc this error is thrown:

`/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by /home/foo/Desktop/sdk/openwrt-sdk-18.06.4-x86-64_gcc-7.3.0_musl.Linux-x86_64/staging_dir/target-x86_64_musl/usr/lib/libpcap.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)`.


I must link to a specific libc.so located somewhere in the OpenWrt SDK subfolders to compile this program successfully. However, is it viable to use that rpath solution the error is suggesting? If so, how?

Comment: @imll Added `-libc` notes for you.